# How to call a global file before running any test suite

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to call a keyword which should be executed prior to the start of any robot tests  and that keyword should be run only once per entire project suite...

eg: Lets say there is a project suite called "ProjectSuite" which contains  4 test suite folders in it like below
 testSuite1
TestSuite2
TestSuite3
And Now there is keyword to update an admin account ,I want to define that keyword in a file and make it as a global one .Also that keyword should be executed first before any of the testsuite folders(testSuite1,TestSuite2,etc) start execution. 
If I pybot testSuite1 ,That keyword should be executed first
If I run TestSuite2, That keyword should be executed first and so on..
If I run ProjectSuite , Then that keyword should be executed only once and should not be run again and again for children testSuites..

For this scenario I have an idea like below
Will write up a keyword and place it in global resource folder
Then call that keyword in `_init_` file under each TestSuites(TestSuite1,TestSuite2..etc)
But the Keyword runs for every suite which is not a good idea
So if any one have a better idea please let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given,

You have a suite ProjectSuite ,
and sub-test-suites 
TestSuite1
TestSuite2
TestSuite3
and a user-keyword pre-test-keyword,

And if you want to execute "pre-test-keyword" prior to executing any of TestSuite1 or TestSuite2 or TestSuite3,

Then the ideal solution will be to define "pre-test-keyword" with a "Suite Setup" tag in the definition of ProjectSuite.
In case ProjectSuite is a directory, this can be done in a "test suite initialization file"

This way "pre-test-keyword" will get executed before any of TestSuite1 or TestSuite2 or TestSuite3.

Details are in this link
http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.6.2#suite-setup-and-teardown

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are three approaches I can think of for this. The first approach is exactly what you describe. Instead of running your keyword directly, create a user keyword which tests for the existence of a global level variable (you pick is name but the principle is that of a C #IFDEF), then if it's not defined run the keyword and set the variable, otherwise do nothing.

The second: Add a global variable to the python file containing your keyword which is initially True, test that variable on running your keyword, and don't do anything if it's set to False. If it's set to True then run the functionality of your keyword and then set it to False. This means that while the keyword is called for every test case, it only does anything the first time it is run.

The third approach would be not to actually use a keyword, but instead a script outside of your test suite, which runs the functionally of your keyword, and then runs the tests.

Which of these you use depends on what your keyword is and why you're running it, more information would be useful in determining what advice to give. The first will log exactly what is happening, the second leaves less cruft in your test log but decreases visibility. The third completely removes visibility; I however use the third in my tests to change to a python virtualenv, install dependencies, and start a logging proxy before running my tests and then shutting down said proxy. The second I use for part of the first time initialisation of a test library in order to perform lengthy calculations on a large data set, the result of which is immutable and is then used by every instance of that library. The first I have not found a use for, but then my tests are not your tests.